# Integer expressed in a power form

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

A number `N` is said to be expressible in a power form if for some `a > 0` and some `x > 1`, we have `N = a^x`.

Now to check this we can take log both sides and equation becomes `log(n)/log(a)=x` so by iterating from `(2,sqrt(n))`if there exists any number that gives `x` as a integer than that number to the power `x` can be expressed as `N`.

Following is my code that checks for the same

```
from math import log,sqrt,floor
n=int(input())
t=floor(sqrt(n))+1
flag=False


for i in range(2,t):
    x=log(n)/log(i)
    if x==int(x):
        print("YESSSSSSSSSSSSS!")
        flag=True
        break

if not flag:
    print("Nooooooooooooooooooo!")
```

Time complexity: *O*(*n*)

Is there any other alternative/better approach to the problem?

Comment: Is this a math or programming question?

Comment: I intend to use for programming but can be treated as a math question.

Comment: Sorry, but then the question is better placed on one of our math related sibling sites.

Comment: Time complexity ONLY for worst case is `O(n)`. What else do you want?

Comment: You would be better off iterating *x* and testing for *x*-th roots than iterating *i* and testing whether *i* is a root, as there are many fewer candidates for *x* than for *i*. The complexity for the former is log(*n*), whereas the latter has complexity sqrt(*n*).

Comment: Time complexity is not your main problem here, float point accuracy is. Try n = 76 ** 89 - 1 and n = 76 ** 89.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks :)

Comment: @Piinthesky Noted.

Comment: Float point accuracy fails even with small numbers `log(1<<29) / log(2) != 29`. You might at least need `x - int(x) < ESP` comparison instead of `==`.

Comment: Good point @BlownhitherMa Even 3 ** 5 fails.

Comment: @Piinthesky What could be the possible solution i have tried x-int(x)<sys.float_info.epsilon but this is not working!

Comment: I ran into similar problems with roots and fractions. I employ two strategies. Use the `decimal` module, to increase float point accuracy. But mainly I don't test `if x == int(x)`, but work instead solely with integers: `if i ** x == n`. Python has (theoretically) unlimited precision for integers. But i am a Python newbie, maybe professionals have better suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better approach would be the following algorithm:

```
x <- 0
i <- 2
found <- false
do
    x <- root(N, i)
    if (x is integer) then
       found <- true
    end if
    i <- i + 1
while (x >= 2) and (not found)
```

This algorithm will be much faster than linear. I think it is logarithmic, but do not have the time ti check it.

Comment: root(N, i) is square root when i is 2, cube root when i is 3 and so on.

Comment: It is logarithmic because it stops at or before *i* reaches the base-two logarithm of *N*. (If *i* is the base-two logarithm of *N*, then root(*N*, *i*) is 2.)

Comment: @LajosArpad  Thanks ,This is what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Demonking28 you are welcome. If my answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct solution.