# how do I check if a number can be expressed as x raised to power y?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need x^y == integer (input)
cant figure out how to do so
***I CANT USE MATH IMPORT***
tried to do something like this:

```
a = int(input("Please Enter any Positive Integer:"))
 power = 1
 i = 1

 while(i <= a):
     power = power * a
    i = i + 1
```

for example
the input is 8
i need the program to find x^y==8
in this case the output needs to be:
x=2
y=3
hope its clear
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some sample inputs and expected output for same. It is not clear from your description what is it you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Kind of duplicate: You can find the factors of the number, and count them if they are all the same : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171765/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-all-the-divisors-of-a-number

Comment: edited please look:)

Comment: its a great answer but I cant use math import :(

Comment: An integer `z` can always be expressed as `x^y = z^1`

Comment: Boldfacing *can't use math import* does not explain anything.

Comment: duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48042029/1435475).

Comment: yeah but they used math import while I said I couldnt....

Answer (score 1):

You can find prime factors and take the greatest common denominator (gcd) of prime counts.

For example 216000's prime factors are 2^6, 3^3, 5^3 so the power will be 3.  For each of the primes keep count/3 as the power to compute the base: 2^2 * 3^1 * 5^1 = 60.  So 216000 = 60^3

```
def primeFactors(N):   # returns dictionary of {prime:count}
    result = dict()
    p = 2              # p is a candidate prime factor   
    while p*p<=N:      # prime candidates up to √N (remaining N) 
        while N%p == 0:   # count prime factors
            result[p] = result.get(p,0)+1 
            N //= p       # by removing factors, only primes will match
        p += 1 + (p&1)    # next potential prime
    if N>1: result[N] = 1 # anything remaining after √N is a prime
    return result

def gcd(a,b=0,*c):                    # gcd using Euclid's algorithm
    if c: return gcd(gcd(a,b),*c)     # for multiple values
    return a if not b else gcd(b,a%b) # Euclidian division version

def findPower(N):
    counts = primeFactors(N)       # {prime factor: count}
    power  = gcd(*counts.values()) # power is gcd of prime counts
    base   = 1                  
    for f,c in counts.items():     # compute base
        base *= f**(c//power)      # from remaining prime powers
    return base,power
```

output:

```
print(findPower(216000))           # (60,3)
print(findPower(8))                # (2,3)
print(findPower(81))               # (3,4)
print(findPower(371293))           # (13,5)
print(findPower(29**7))            # (29,7)
print(findPower(1522756**5553))    # (1234, 11106) 
print(findPower(12345**12345))     # (12345,12345)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
def findfactors(number):
    factors = []
    search = number
    for n in range(2, number//2):
        while search%n==0:
            factors.append(n)
            search = search // n
    if search != 1:
        factors.append(search)
    return factors


def findxpowery(number):
    res = findfactors(number)
    diffactors = set(res)
    
    #print("factors: ", res)
    #print("different factors", diffactors)
    
    res2 = [res.count(x) for x in diffactors]
    #print("count the different factors", res2)
    
    
    rr = 1
    for r in diffactors:
        rr = rr*r
    #print("multiplicate all the different factors", rr)
    
    
    
    if len(set(res2))==1:
        #print("solution is", rr, "^", list(set(res2))[0])
        return (rr, list(set(res2))[0])
    else:
        #print("no solution")
        return None

number = (9**2)
r = findxpowery(number)
print("solution is", number, "=", r[0], "^", r[1])
```

Output is :

```
solution is 81 = 3 ^ 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve, this should work, I'm sure someone else can give you a better solution though.

```
    a = int(input("Please Enter any Positive Integer:"))
    max_ = round(a**(1/2)+1)


    for x in range(2, max_):
        for y in range(2, max_):
    
            p = x**y
            if p == a:
        
                print(x,'power',y)
                print(p)
        
            elif p > a:
                pass
```

Comment: my pleasure glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

To check if a number `a` can be a perfect power of `x` you may check

```
x ** int(round(math.log(a, x))) == a
```

Then to find out if there it is a perfect number of anything, loop from 2, to the square root of the value

```
from math import sqrt, log, ceil

def find_perfect_power(a):
    for value in range(2, ceil(sqrt(a)) + 1):
        if value ** int(round(log(a, value))) == a:
            return True, value, int(round(math.log(a, value)))
    return False,
```

Example

```
for i in range(1, 30):
    r = find_perfect_power(i)
    if r[0]:
        print(i, r)

2 (True, 2, 1)
4 (True, 2, 2)
8 (True, 2, 3)
9 (True, 3, 2)
16 (True, 2, 4)
25 (True, 5, 2)
27 (True, 3, 3)
```

Comment: added an example :)

Comment: I cant use import.math sadly

Comment: Poor algorithm (in respect to runtime complexity), unconvincing implementation (`value`as identifier is not exactly descriptive).

Answer (score -1):

```
num = int(input("enter number: ")) 
# if you have x and y values for example x = 5 and y = 5
x = 5 
y = 5 
if x ** y == num:
    print("True") 
else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: hi! I need to find x and y given a num as an input

Comment: added an example